# Unity Запуск анимации при старте в вечный повтор

Tags: unity3d, анимация

Сделал анимацию модели в блендере, сохранил в dae, импортировал в unity анимация импортировалась,и запускается в  редакторе работает, но при перемещении на сцену и запуске анимация не работает. Мне нужно чтобы при старте игры анимация постоянно работала как это сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

получить доступ к аниматору public Animator anim;
А что бы анимация работала постоянно написать этот кусочек кода anim.Play("") в Update

Comment: а можно поподробнее у меня переменной anim не существует

Comment: С помощью этой переменной получаешь доступ к Аниматору, далее затягиваешь его в редакторе. И далее в Update записуешь anim.Play("название анимации ");